# itext PDF libraries for using PDF templates

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation

Are there any libraries written in .NET which are equivalent to iText DITO (which uses Java).
I'm looking for something which allows the PDF document structure and layout to be defined in some external PDF template which can then have placeholder text replaced with text for product items from our ecommerce catalog.

Comment: Library recommendations strictly speaking are off-topic here and should be asked on the software recommendations stack exchange site.

Comment: iText DITO is also available as a Docker container (https://hub.docker.com/r/itext/dito-sdk) so you can use it from any programming language, with a RESTful API. More info on the iText blog: https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/itext-news/convenient-design-containerization-itext-dito-v-12